# Menu's built in the edit theme view do not have active states set when on child pages

Tags: menus, woocommerce-offtopic

have a menu that is pulled in like this:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu ( array('menu' => 'header') ) ?>
```

I am using WooCommerce and when visiting /shop the shop link in the header has the class: current_page_item

However, when viewing a single product the menu link has no active class.

This is also the case when viewing categories etc.

The link in the URL /shop/category/phone/ shows it has a parent of the shop page but no active states.

Is it possible to set WordPress to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The shop link in your menu gets the "current_page_parent" class when your on a product page.
If you have any WooCommerce categories in your menu, they will get "current-product-parent" as a class when you're on e product page from that category.

Simply give those classes the same styling as your active class.